# SF: Merge/Re-tag [windows] [xp] to [windows-xp]

Tags: support, retag-request

ServerFault:

`[windows][xp]` -> `[windows-xp]` (24)

`[xp]` -> `[windows-xp]` (57)

There's also

`[vista]` (297) -> `[windows-vista]` (48)

so I guess `[vista]` should win, but this is inconsistant with `[windows-xp]` and `[windows-7]`... (perhaps this is where synonyms would be great)

Comment: I would vote to take [vista] -> [windows-vista], even given the totals.

Comment: Please note that making [windows] and [xp] into [windows-xp] would cause a list of items under the [windows] tag to no longer include windows xp

Answer (score 6):

`[windows-vista]` is better than `[vista]` even if there are fewer of those in use. However, `[vista]` will keep coming back if synonyms aren't instituted.. :(

Comment: Sysnonyms are on the plate for the developers.  It is in `status-planned`.  Anyways, I agree here.  +1 for `windows-vista`.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update: I've merged some of the most common windows-... combinations. I'll keep an eye on it.